# Count distinct in window functions

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to count of unique column b for each c, with out doing group by. I know this could be done with join. how to do count(distinct b) over (partition by c) with out resorting to join. Why are count distinct not supported in window functions. Thank you in advance. 
Given this data frame:

```scala
val df= Seq(("a1","b1","c1"),
                ("a2","b2","c1"),
                ("a3","b3","c1"),
                ("a31",null,"c1"),
                ("a32",null,"c1"),
                ("a4","b4","c11"),
                ("a5","b5","c11"),
                ("a6","b6","c11"),
                ("a7","b1","c2"),
                ("a8","b1","c3"),
                ("a9","b1","c4"),
                ("a91","b1","c5"),
                ("a92","b1","c5"),
                ("a93","b1","c5"),
                ("a95","b2","c6"),
                ("a96","b2","c6"),
                ("a97","b1","c6"),
                ("a977",null,"c6"),
                ("a98",null,"c8"),
                ("a99",null,"c8"),
                ("a999",null,"c8")
                ).toDF("a","b","c");
```

Comment: finally this one worked for me:
````
df. .withColumn("count_distinct", expr(" dense_rank() over (partition by c order by b desc)+dense_rank() over (partition by c order by b asc)- max(case when b is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by c)-1  "))
````

Let me know if this one has bug or issue. it also excludes null from the counts

Comment: Are you looking for a pure SQL solution, or something in spark? You tagged both.

Answer (score 1):

Some databases do support `count(distinct)` as a window function. 
 There are two alternatives.  One is the sum of dense ranks:

```
select (dense_rank() over (partition by c order by b asc) +
        dense_rank() over (partition by c order by b desc) -
        1
       ) as count_distinct
from t;
```

The second uses a subquery:

```
select sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by c)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by c order by b) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

> count of unique column b for each c without doing group by.

A typical SQL workaround is to use a subquery that selects distincts tuples, and then a window count in the outer query:

```
SELECT c, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY c) cnt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT b, c FROM mytable) x
```